# ImportError: cannot import name 'AxisError' from 'scipy._lib._util'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conda, mediapipe

i try to training data using conda (tf env),but i getting error like this,

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'AxisError' from 'scipy._lib._util' (/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py)

thats started from since i import lib

import csv

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

RANDOM_SEED = 42

i use:
Numpy Version: 1.26.4
tensorflow version 2.12.0


then i got error,like this :

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33315/3738166321.py in ?()
      1 import csv
      2 
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import tensorflow as tf
----> 5 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      6 
      7 RANDOM_SEED = 42

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in ?()
     83     from . import (
     84         __check_build,  # noqa: F401
     85         _distributor_init,  # noqa: F401
     86     )
---> 87     from .base import clone
     88     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     89 
     90     __all__ = [

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in ?()
     15 
     16 from . import __version__
     17 from ._config import config_context, get_config
     18 from .exceptions import InconsistentVersionWarning
---> 19 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     20 from .utils._estimator_html_repr import _HTMLDocumentationLinkMixin, estimator_html_repr
     21 from .utils._metadata_requests import _MetadataRequester, _routing_enabled
     22 from .utils._param_validation import validate_parameter_constraints

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in ?()
     18 from .. import get_config
     19 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning
     20 from . import _joblib, metadata_routing
     21 from ._bunch import Bunch
---> 22 from ._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     23 from ._param_validation import Integral, Interval, validate_params
     24 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     25 from .deprecation import deprecated

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_estimator_html_repr.py in ?()
      6 from pathlib import Path
      7 from string import Template
      8 
      9 from .. import __version__, config_context
---> 10 from .fixes import parse_version
     11 
     12 
     13 class _IDCounter:

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py in ?()
     13 
     14 import numpy as np
     15 import scipy
     16 import scipy.sparse.linalg
---> 17 import scipy.stats
     18 import threadpoolctl
     19 
     20 import sklearn

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py in ?()
    601 """  # noqa: E501
    602 
    603 from ._warnings_errors import (ConstantInputWarning, NearConstantInputWarning,
    604                                DegenerateDataWarning, FitError)
--> 605 from ._stats_py import *
    606 from ._variation import variation
    607 from .distributions import *
    608 from ._morestats import *

~/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py in ?()
     35 from numpy import array, asarray, ma
     36 
     37 from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
     38 from scipy.ndimage import _measurements
---> 39 from scipy._lib._util import (check_random_state, MapWrapper, _get_nan,
     40                               rng_integers, _rename_parameter, _contains_nan,
     41                               AxisError)
     42 

ImportError: cannot import name 'AxisError' from 'scipy._lib._util' (/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py)
```

plz help me

what's the solution?